# why does prime numbers appear in the some of hexagons in a larger hexagon ( like beehive shapes)?

Tags: geometry

lets take a small example for explanation, here is a 3 by 3 hexagon

[image: 3 by 3 hexagon]

the number of hexagons inside the big one is 7 which is a prime number
doing the same with 4 by 4 hexagon give us : (2x4)+(2x5)+(2x6)+7=37 again a prime number
5 by 5 hexagon we get 61 prime number
[image: 5 by 5 hexagon]
but with 6 by 6 we get 91 which is not a prime number however if we do 7 by 7 we get 127 another prime number
my questions is :
is there a prove for such K where this sum is always a prime number ?

Comment: No, $7$ is for $2\times 2$. Your sequence is $7,19,37,61,\ldots $

Comment: There are lots of primes among the small numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sequence is [A003215](https://oeis.org/search?q=7%2C19%2C37%2C61%2C91%2C127&language=english&go=Search), the crystal ball sequence for hexagonal lattice:
$$
1, 7, 19, 37, 61, 91, 127, 169, 217, 271, \ldots
$$
A closed formula is given by
$$
a_n=3n(n+1)+1.
$$
This sequence contains many prime numbers and many composite numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As already observed, the sequence is $3n(n+1)+1$. This sequence contains an infinity of composite integers (that's not hard to prove) and probably has an infinity of primes (but that's an open problem, nobody knows).

If we define the function $A(m) = |\{n \le m : a_n \text{ is prime}\}|$ to have a measure of how many terms of the sequence are primes, a conjecture in number theory tell us that $$A(m) \sim C\frac{m}{\log m}$$ where $$C = \frac{1}{2}\prod_{p}\frac{p-\nu(p)}{p-1}\approx 1.68$$ and $\nu(p) = 2$ if $p\equiv 1 \pmod 6$ and $0$ otherwise.